# Xamarin forms content view does not showing when I click once but need to click twice

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I trying to display a content page in content view.

My problem is :

when I tap on the StackLayout "Ontest" the content view is  blank.

If I want to see it I need to tap a second time

My question :

**Is there a way to refresh a content view ?**

using "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread Does not work   :

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            });
```

Here is the code :

```
public void OnTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             LoadtestPage();
        }




        public   void  LoadtestPage()
        {

            
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                HomeView.IsVisible = false;
                TestView.IsVisible = true;
                TestView.Content = new TestWordsPage().Content; 
            });

        }



            

            public void OnMyWords(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {

           TestView.IsVisible = false;
           HomeView.IsVisible = true;

            });
        }
```

Comment: This is not the recommended approach. You can try the MVVM. That will be more efficient way.

Comment: @Anurag do you have another way that can help me to refresh  my content view

Comment: Set true in constructor before binding.

Comment: @Shaw what if I need to set it to false before setting to true ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Could you describe your expected actions and behaviour, like "run - white page - click - display". And could you post your whole class and xaml page please?